# How do I edit a Spree Commerce store's HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, themes, spree, spree-auth-devise

Here's the situation:

I have a Spree Commerce test server up and running along with some test pages that I've designed. The test pages are simple HTML documents with CSS, and a little bit of JS. However, in Spree, I can't seem to find any of the source HTML! I can change the favicon, logo, etc, but I just can't figure out how to edit the different pages as traditional web pages. For example, if I inspect the stylesheet that the home page is getting information from, the filepath is
`http://192.168.1.36/assets/spree/frontend/frontend_bootstrap.self-a11dc5cbe11602096f96896fb7a08267c908a596138065eef809a197c0fc7d50.css`

yet that file does not exist server-side. There's gotta be a way to integrate some of the code from the other pages so everything's consistent...

Thanks.

---

**Useful information:**

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 Server
- Spree Version 3.0.0
- Ruby Version 2.2.2 x86_64-linux

Comment: Everything is consistent, those parts come from varius spree gems. If you want to override them either use `Deface::Override` (check gem's page for info how) or create new file with same path and name in your project.

Comment: I recommend you go through the Spree source code and developer documentation. It'll give you some great pointers as to how to find your way about various problems.